# Firefox gives error for an event object

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, event-handling

This code works great on chrome, but wont work on IE or Firefox.

```
$('.modal').on("click", ".action", function() {
    if($(event.target).hasClass('added')) {
        if($(event.target).hasClass('remove_vehicle')) {
           //code
        }
```

I get this error on the Firefox console:

```
ReferenceError: event is not defined
[Break On This Error]   

if($(event.target).hasClass('added')) {
```

What is wrong here? Both `event.trigger` and `hasClass` are supposed to work on Firefox.

Comment: Firefox does not have window.event object :)) And I think it is not useful..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this -

```
$('.modal').on("click", ".action", function(event) { // see the difference in this line 
    if($(event.target).hasClass('added')) {
        if($(event.target).hasClass('remove_vehicle')) {
           //code
        }
```

Comment: That did it. 10 minutes until I can accept your answer. By any chance do you have an explanation for this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `this` instead of `event.target`. As a matter of fact `event` is a reserved variable that might be defined on some browsers but not on other. The proper way is this:

```
$('.modal').on('click', '.action', function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('added') && $(this).hasClass('remove_vehicle')) {  
        //code
    }
});
```